# CSS ruins link (<a>)

Tags: html, css

I have a link that did not work on my page. The link in the header works, but the second link does not. I cut out the CSS and both links work. What in the following CSS would cause a link to not work?

```
.sidenav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  /*top set by $*/
  background-color: #2e2e2e; 
}

.sidenav a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.sidenav a:not(.disrupt):hover {
  border-left: 2px solid #ff9500;
  border-right: 2px solid #ff9500;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<body ontouchstart>
  <div class="header">
   <div class="logo">Q<sup>3</sup></div>
   <a href="http://www.google.com">hello</a>
   <div class="desc">Quito's Qustom Qode</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <div id="content" class="col10">

     <div class="about">

      <div class="profile-back">
       <div class="profile"></div>
      </div>
     </div><!-- /about -->
    <a href="http://www.google.com">hello</a>
   </div><!-- /content -->
  </div><!-- /row -->
 </body>
```

I've looked at this code and have commented portions I thought would be doing it and got nothing. I know it is the CSS because (again) I commented out the CSS file link and the second works, but when it is added, it fails.

EDIT: The CSS that is left is what I commented out and the link worked.
EDIT: It appears that the `/*top set by jQ*/` moves the main content over and breaks the link.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing a complete example. We'll need a [mcve]

Comment: two anchor in your code, which one is ruins what?

Comment: a { ruin: not; } JK

Comment: Please put only the relevant code that affects the link element you are talking about. Any other code, makes it really hard to debug anything.

Comment: That's the problem: I don't know what affects the link, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `.header` having `position: fixed` covers the link.
To check this guess, please in Chrome or Firefox make right click on the link, select `Inspect` from the context menu and look which element will be inspected.

100% that it won't be the link.

**Update:** Thanks for the author's comment, the issue is

```
#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 16.66%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  z-index: -1;  <---------- HERE
}
```

`z-index: -1` puts `#content` block under the `body`

Comment: Inspecting the link gives the body tag in Chrome

Comment: The `z-index` was the problem. I was trying to make sure the content did not come over the header. I have changed the header to have `z-index: 1` now. Everything seems to work. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but the `.sidenav a:not(.disrupt):hover` is the issue.

Comment: And how did you fix the issue?